# deleting from the database does not work with apis in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-9

The process of deleting from the database does not work with apis in laravel
I created a function that deletes from database but my code doesn't work

```
  public function deletePatient($id) 
    {  
         $patient =Patient::find($id);
          if(!sizeof($patient)==0) {
            $patient->delete();
          return response()->json([
            "message" => "Patient is  deleted"
          ], 200);
        } else {
          return response()->json([
            "message" => "Patient not found"
          ], 404);
        }
      }
```

route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Api\ApisController;
Route::delete('/api/deletepatient/{id}',[ApisController::class,'deletePatient']);
```

Postman
Delete : http://localhost:8000/api/deletepatient/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be complicating things a bit, try the following:

```
public function deletePatient(Patient $id)
{
    if (!$patient->delete()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to delete patient'], 404);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Patient deleted'], 204);
}
```

We're using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) to have Laravel automatically find the relevant `Patient` model from the database for us, if one is not found it will throw a `404 - Not Found` error for us. Alternatively you could use `Patient::findOrFail($id);` if you wanted to.

If the `delete` operation was not successful, return an error response (you can customise this to your liking), otherwise return a success response. Usually this is a `204 - No Content`.

Comment: When using postman It returns me a page <title>Page Expired</title>

Comment: @AbdulsalamSawalha A `419 - Page Expired` error is caused by a [`CSRF token mismatch`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf). `CSRF` tokens are not usually used with APIs and this check is usually performed by the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware on all routes defined in `web.php`. Make sure this route is defined in your `api.php` not `web.php` route file and then clear your caches before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the error, but I would suggest to try
without "/api" on your route

```
Route::delete('/deletepatient/{id}',[ApisController::class,'deletePatient']);
```

I would do it like that:

```
public function deletePatient($id) 
{  
     if (!$patient = Patient::find($id)) {
      
         return response()->json([
             "message" => "Patient not found"
         ], 404);            
     }
     
     $patient->delete();

     return response()->json([
          "message" => "Patient has been deleted"
     ], 200);        
    
  }
```

Comment: When using postman
It returns me a page

<title>Page Expired</title>

Answer (score 0):

Please try clear your cache:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```